# How to find named indexes in array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Sorry if I mistyped the question, but I am not sure how to explain this question. I am showing the value that I want by code below. I have an array with named indexes:

```
const comments = [
 {K6TTWcffVUQNryy19FrSVKYL6Wt2: {age:25,name:"john"}}, 
 {AXYVWcffVUQNryy19FrSVKYL6Wt3: {age:35,name:"sue"}}
]
```

I am trying to find the named indxes of the array of objects. I mean I am trying to create an array of `["K6TTWcffVUQNryy19FrSVKYL6Wt2", "AXYVWcffVUQNryy19FrSVKYL6Wt3"]` using the above `comments` array.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get the properties of an object you can use `for in` loop, or `Object.keys(yourObj)`

```js
const comments = [{
    K6TTWcffVUQNryy19FrSVKYL6Wt2: {
      age: 25,
      name: "john"
    }
  },
  {
    AXYVWcffVUQNryy19FrSVKYL6Wt3: {
      age: 35,
      name: "sue"
    }
  }
]

var result = comments.map(function(item) {
  for (var prop in item) {
    // the first one
    return prop
  }
})

console.log(result)

// or
console.log(comments.map(item => Object.keys(item)[0]))
```

Comment: I will accept this answer if not any better approach comes. Can't we use Object.keys(comments)... smt like this in such situation?

Comment: of course I forgot about it. but actually this approach is more efficient. either way if you still want the 1 liner: `comments.map(item => Object.keys(item)[0])`

Comment: I was searching for this one liner, thx a lot man!!! I was putting the [0] like this  Object.keys(item[0]) and therefore mistaking. Accepting your answer, thx a lot !

Answer (score 2):

You could map the keys.

```js
const
    comments = [{ K6TTWcffVUQNryy19FrSVKYL6Wt2: { age: 25, name: "john" } }, { AXYVWcffVUQNryy19FrSVKYL6Wt3: { age: 35, name: "sue" } }],
    keys = comments.flatMap(Object.keys);

console.log(keys);
```

Comment: nice one.......

Comment: flatmap takes only the first parameters to create a new array?

Comment: what do you mean with "*first parameters*"?

Answer (score 1):

A combination of `Array::reduce()` and `Object.keys()`:

```js
const comments = [
 {K6TTWcffVUQNryy19FrSVKYL6Wt2: {age:25,name:"john"}}, 
 {AXYVWcffVUQNryy19FrSVKYL6Wt3: {age:35,name:"sue"}}
];

const result = Object.keys(comments.reduce((r, el) => Object.assign(r, el), {}));

console.log(result);
```